# Share .Net Authorisation Cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authorization

I have developed an ASPNET WebAPI service that uses form authentication with cookies.

I also have a main website which authenticates against my ASPNET WebAPI and serves some content from it.

So my workflow basically is:

1. Client/Browser authenticates against the main website.
2. Main website (server) authenticates against ASPNET WebAPI and receives an authentication cookie.

After logging in the client will need to access some content of the ASPNET WebAPI via server and also via browser.

I would like to know if it is possible to re-use the same cookie that the server received in the browser. Ideally my website server receives the cookie and push it to the client browser. I am assuming that ASPNET Authorisation cookies are not IP-specific, since the client browser and the server IPs are different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by modifying your configuration such as:

```
<forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
    protection="All"  
    path="/" 
    domain="yourdomain.com" 
    timeout="30" />
```

Remember that both sites must be on the same domain, and the cookie path must be set to a common root or /.

Comment: Thanks @Borys-Generalov, but the two sites (WebAPI and main website) are in different domains.